# comparing a char to a const char *

Tags: c++

```
string line = "blerdy blah";
for (int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++)
{

    line[i] != "n";
}
```

With this I get the error "cannot convert from char to const char *"

If I replace the last line with

```
line[i] != *"n";
```

It works. I get why in one sense, I'm dereferencing a pointer. What I don't get is why it's a pointer in the first place. Is any char written like this actually a pointer to one char somewhere? Like the program has one set of every symbol somewhere and this is what I'm pointing to?

If this is the case, can I do silly things like make the 'n' pointer point to something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to compare `char` with `char` in this case:

```
line[i] != 'n';
```

When you say `*"n"` you actually dereference the first element of the char array with `n` and `\0` elements inside it, which gives you `n`, that's why it works, but you don't want to write it like that.

Answer (score 10):

`"n"` is not a character literal, it is a string literal. You want `'n'`.

Comment: +1 I think stating that "" is a string literal gives this answer the most value.

Answer (score 2):

"n" is a char array (string). While 'n' is a char.

Answer (score 2):

`"n"` is a so called string literal, which has the type `const char[2]`. `string::operator[]` (actually `basic_string<char>::operator[]` returns a `const char&` or `char&` depending on the picked overload (the second one in this case). You cannot compare those types. What you want want to compare the result of `operator[]` to is a character literal, which is written as `'n'`.

**For your second question**

`"n"` has type `const char[2]`, dereferencing it gives you a `char` (the first character in the array pointed to). This is equivalent to `"n"[0]`.

Comment: Nitpick: "n" has type `const char[2]`, not `const char*`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks. I always mess that up.

Comment: does this mean if I initialise and empty string like this: string foo = ""; it's wrong? Is there a better way? Can I just do string foo; ?

Comment: @Sir: No that's not wrong.  It calls the string constructor that takes a const char *.  However, yes, if you want an empty string, you can simply create the string without arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Change `"n"` to `'n'`. The difference is that the former is a `const char*` whereas the latter is `char`. Since you want to compare one `char` to another, the latter is the correct form to use.

Answer (score 0):

### Why and how this works

Start with `"n"`: lexically it is a null-terminated string literal, which means that the compiler will end up treating it as a `char*` pointing to a section of memory that holds the string "n".

So when you write `*"n"`, what happens is that you are dereferencing a `char*` that points to `"n"`, which means that the result of the expression will be `'n'` (of type `char`). That's why the comparison to `line[i]` (which is also a `char`) works.

This pointer to `"n"` is a compile-time constant (so you can't change it) and in all likelihood will point to a read-only memory page (so you won't be able to change what it points to at runtime either).

### What you should do instead

```
line[i] != 'n'; // compare char to char
```